# Conjecture: for perfect graphs the fractional chromatic index rounded up equals the chromatic index

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

Let $\chi'_f(G)$ be the fractional chromatic index.

Based on limited experiments (up to 8 vertices and few larger graphs),
I suspect:

**Conjecture** For perfect graphs $\lceil \chi'_f(G) \rceil = \chi'(G)$

**Conjecture 2 (new)** For cubic claw-free perfect graphs $\lceil \chi'_f(G) \rceil = \chi'(G)$

**Conjecture 3 (new)** For claw-free perfect graphs $\lceil \chi'_f(G) \rceil = \chi'(G)$

Sage's `fractional_chromatic_index()` is not efficient for me,
is there another implementation?

Counterexamples or proof (especially of (2)) are welcome.

Observe that the question is about **edge coloring**,
not for vertex coloring.

Comment: Related question on cstheory SE at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/24915 For which graph classes the fractional chromatic index rounded up equals the chromatic index?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A result of Cai and Ellis (see Theorem 5 in http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166218X9190010T) implies that deciding whether a cubic perfect line-graph is $3$-edge-colorable is NP-complete. Counter-examples to Conjecture 2 can be built from their argument as follows:

First, notice that every cubic bridgeless graph $G$ satisfies $\chi_f'(G)=3$. This is easily obtained using the following formula for $\chi_f'(G)$, which is derived from Edmonds' inequalities for the matching polytope of $G$:
$$\chi_f'(G)=\max\left(\Delta(G),\max_{U\subseteq V(G), |U|\geq 3\, \text{odd}}\frac{|E(U)|}{\frac{|U|-1}{2}}\right).$$

Now, consider the following construction: let $H$ be a bridgeless cubic graph and $S(H)$ be the graph obtained from $H$ by subdividing each edge exactly once. Let $G$ be the line graph of $S(H)$.

It is straightforward to check that $G$ is cubic, bridgeless and that: $\chi'(G)=3$ if and only if $\chi'(H)=3$. Furthermore, $G$ is perfect because $S(H)$ is bipartite.

Therefore, if $H$ is a cubic bridgeless graph with $\chi'(H)=4$ (for example the Petersen graph or any other *snark* [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snark_(graph_theory)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snark_%28graph_theory%29)), then $G$ is a cubic bridgeless perfect line-graph with $\chi'(G)>\lceil\chi_f'(G)\rceil$.

Comment: Thank you Johan, this appears indeed a counterexample :)

Answer (score 8):

It is shown in "On claw-free t-perfect graphs" by Bruhn and Stein that indeed
$\lceil \chi'_f(G) \rceil = \chi'(G)$ holds for claw-free $h$-perfect graphs, see corollary $16$. This also holds for $h$-perfect line-graphs and $t$-perfect claw-free graphs, see the paper of [Benchetrit](http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.0757), 
Theorem $3$ and Theorem $4$. However, Benchetrit says that it does
not hold for $h$-perfect graphs in general (see the remark with references after Theorem $4$). So there are counterexamples (by Laurent and
Seymour in 2003).

Comment: What is the exact reference for the counterexample (the paper shows counterexample about _vertex_ coloring). And except for sharing the name "perfect" why their results apply to perfect graphs?

Comment: Perfect graphs are also $h$-perfect. To the first question - $t$-perfetc graphs with the integer round-up property must have chromatic number at most $3$. The examples of Laurent and Seymour are t-perfect graphs which are not 3-colorable.

Comment: Sorry, but I am asking about EDGE coloring (chromatic INDEX) and you answer about VERTEX coloring (chromatic NUMBER). Assume G is claw-free (will edit). Would you please explain about EDGE coloring?

Comment: I see. This "index" is the fractional edge chromatic number, which is given by the fractional chromatic number of the associated line graph, right ?

Comment: Yes. The fractional chromatic number of the line graph L(G) is equal the fractional chromatic index of G, so line graph might help. Again, assume G is perfect claw free graph (will edit).

Comment: Edited with two relaxations.